# iTunes Music Match files in MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes, icloud, mpmediapickercontroller

I have made an app using MPMediaPickerController that allows the user to pick songs from their music library.

It is great that when you turn on iTunes Music match the MPMediaPickerController automatically includes iTunes Music Match tracks as well...

However, the usage is not as good as it could be.

first photo shows the "cloud" icon, if you click it , the song "downloads" but there is no indication of if it is indeed downloading or any sort of progress bar...

[image: itunes music match icons shown in MPMediaPickerController]

The iPad music library does show an indicator when you click a cloud icon and shows the progress of the music match file download.

[image: progress bar for music library..]

Is this possible to turn this on using a MPMediaPickerController ? or any ideas how I can display this kind of progress information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can poll the MPMediaItem's MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL, and show an indeterminate progress or activity indicator until the MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL returns a URL beginning with "ipod-library://" (it should return nil until then). You won't know the actual progress of the download, but you can tell the user when it's ready to play back.